# Unreachable error

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to have the code print out the highest of the three grades; however, the if/else statement in the highest method is finding an error in return d. I have tried putting if(d>b && d>c) return d, and also else return d. But both times the program says it is unreachable. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong? Thank you!

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Methods2 {
      public static double average(double a){
        double ave= a/3.0;
        return ave;
      }
      public static double highest(double b, double c, double d){
        if(b>c && b>d)
          return b;
        if(c>b && c>d);
          return c;
        return d;//unreachable code 
      }
      public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner kb= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your name.");
        String name = kb.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter your three grades.");
        double b= kb.nextDouble();
        double c= kb.nextDouble();
        double d= kb.nextDouble();
        double av= average(b+c+d);
        System.out.println(av);
        double high= highest(b,c,d);
        System.out.println(high);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because of the semicolon in the second if

```
if(c>b && c>d);
```

That terminates the conditional statement right there and `return c;` becomes a statement that will get executed regardless of condition,  remove it

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Because semicolon makes it an empty `if` body.

```
if(c>b && c>d);
    return c;
```

should be

```
if(c>b && c>d)
    return c;
```

or (the arguably better)

```
if(c>b && c>d) {
    return c;
}
```

You could also use [`Math.max(double, double)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#max%28double,%20double%29) to make this a one line method like

```
public static double highest(double b, double c, double d) {
    return Math.max(d, Math.max(b, c));
}
```